# jQuery in Grails 1.3.7

Tags: jquery, grails, jquery-plugins

Can you please tell how to connect a jquery plugin in Grails 1.3.7.

While trying to install with the command "grails install-plugin jquery" from within a directory with the plugin appears the following text

> "Resolving dependencies ... Dependencies resolved in 798ms. Running
>   script C: \ grails \ scripts \ InstallPlugin.groovy Environment set to
>   development Application expects grails version [1.3.5], but
>   GRAILS_HOME is version [1.3.7] - use the correct Grails version or run
>   'grails upgrade' if this Grails version is newer than the version your
>   application expects. "

Trying to install jQuery Plugin 1.4.4.1 with http://grails.org.
I would be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a version mismatch between the version of Grails that you're currently using and the version that was used when your application was originally created.  Run 'grails-upgrade' and when that is complete, try installing your plugin again.  You're not going to be able to install the jQuery plugin until you resolve the version mismatch issue.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

you can change  app.grails.version in application.properties file